# Increasing a variable set as a percentage

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to increase the value of the variable "Char" which is set to a elements position from the left;
The value "Char" is a percentage set as a css element
I am trying to increase "Char" so that the element will move when i press the arrow keys
Here is my code:

```
function handleMovement(e) {
  var Char = document.getElementById("Character").style;
  if (event.code == "ArrowLeft") {
    Char.position = "absolute";
    Char.left - "10%";
  } else if (event.code == "ArrowRight") {
    Char.position = "absolute";
    Char.left + "10%"
  }
}
```

If worked correctly the right arrow key will move the element 10% to the left and the right will move it 10% to the right EACH TIME it is pressed

I tried adding "10%" to Char.left but that made the element not move
I also tried + 10 + "%" which also did not work

I am expecting the element to move 10% to the respected direction EACH TIME the arrow key is pressed

I need this to move every time the arrow key is pressed (Ex: if the left key is pressed 3 times it should have moved 30% to the left in total)

Comment: Track the value as a separate variable so you can append the percent sign _after_ the math.

Comment: Just to add to @isherwood's comment: The [data-](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) attribute might be a good place to store this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `parseInt`, which will ignore the percentage sign. I'd write your code like this:

```js
document.addEventListener('keyup', e => {
  let c = document.getElementById("Character");
  let delta = {'ArrowLeft': -10, 'ArrowRight': 10}[e.code]
  if(delta) c.style.left = `${parseInt(c.style.left)+delta}%`
})
```

```html
<div>
  <div id="Character" 
    style="position:absolute; left: 0%; width:10px; height:10px;
           background-color:red">
  </div>
</div>
```